# Lipschitz continuity of truncated $x_i|x|^{-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $n\geq 2$, $C>0$, $i=1,...,n$ and define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
C^{-n}x_i & |x|\leq C\\ 
 |x|^{-n}x_i& |x|\geq C
\end{matrix}\right.$.

> Show that $f$ is Lipschitz

Both the functions $x\mapsto x_i, x\mapsto \left\{\begin{matrix}
C^{-n}& |x|\leq C\\ 
 |x|^{-n}& |x|\geq C
\end{matrix}\right.$ are Lipschitz and the second one is also bounded.$f$ is bounded too as $x_i|x|^{-n}$ vanishes as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$, being $n\geq 2$. These observations make $f$ a bounded locally Lipschitz function, however I don't think this fact will help.

I guess I have to resort to the definition of Lipschitz continuity, but I couldn't come up with anything clever. The problems arise when computing $|f(x)-f(y)|$ for $|x|,|y|$ not both $\leq C$. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand what $i$ does in the definition. Should $f$ have an $i$ index?

Comment: $i$ is a generic index (component of $x$ as a point), to be precise $f$ should have that same index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is separately Lipschitz on $B(0,C)$ and its complement. You might as well choose the same constant $L$

Pick $x,y$. If $x,y$ are both in $B(0,C)$ or the complement then clearly $|f(x)-f(y)| \le L\|x-y\|$.

If $x \in B(0,C) $ and $y$ in the complement then let $t \in [0,1]$ be such that
$z=tx+(1-t)y $ is on the boundary.

Then $|f(x)-f(y)| \le |f(x)-f(z)| + |f(z)-f(y)| \le L(\|x-z\|+\|z-y\|) = L\|x-y\|$.

**Note**:

If $\phi(x) = \|x\|^n$, then $D\phi(x)h = n \|x\|^{n-1} x^T h$ and so
with $\eta(x) = {1 \over \|x\|^n}$ we have
$D \eta(x)h = -n{ 1 \over \|x\|^{n+2}} x^Th$. In particular,
$\|D\eta(x)\| \le n { 1 \over \|x\|^{n+1}}$, so we can see that with $\|x\|>C$ we have 
$\|Df(x)\| \le K {1 \over \|x\|^{n}}$ for some $K$. Hence $f$ is Lipschitz with rank $K$ for $\|x\| > C$.

Comment: This partly solves my problem, however one of the main issues I had was dealing with Lipschitz continuity of $f$ outside the ball.

Comment: @warm_fish: Its just a matter of grinding through the computation.